# awk returns lines with substring

Tags: awk

I have a text file:

```
string 323
blah 23
string_substring 33
```

When my bash variable $f = 'string', I want to return only the number in the first line with awk using

```
awk -F" " -v x=$f '$1 ~ x {print $2}' file.txt
```

Even when I use the field separator of " " , it returns both the first and third line... How can I get it to match only the first line? Is there a way to say $1 = x, i.e. that the first argument is exactly x, and nothing more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If string is the first column use that as a condition :

```
awk '$1=="string" {print $2}' file
```

or from a shell variable,

```
var="string"
awk -v f=$var '$1==f {print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

When you say:

```
$1 ~ x
```

you specify that the first field *matches* `x`.  If you want it to be equal, say so:

```
$1 == x
```

As such, say:

```
awk -F" " -v x=$f '$1 == x {print $2}' file.txt
```